# Is it possible to define a custom fireEvent in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, testing-library

So I know it is possible to create custom queries in `React Testing Library` by using the `buildQuries` helper function, but Is there a way to define some helper to for example get an input by its label and then change its value?

I tried to create a custom query and inside it call `fireEvent`, but couldn't make it work.

The function I need will look something like this:

```js
changeInputWithLabel(labelText, targetText): {
   fireEvent.change(getByLabelText(labelText), {target: {value: targetText}});
}
```